# Input an english word, get back an integer

Tags: javascript

I work in a college radio station, and we want a way to catalogue our physical music with numbers. I want to take the artist, release name, and year, and compute it into a 9 digit number.

I have a few things coded already.

Function bijection(letter) will read a single character, reference var alpha = ["0","1","2",..."9","a","b",..."x","y","z"], and return the index of the provided character. So, bijection(c) = 13, for example.

```
function bijection(character){
    var alpha = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
    var position = alpha.indexOf(character) + 1;
    return position;
}
```

Function easyread(string) will take a string of characters, and remove the spaces. So, easyread("two door cinema club") returns twodoorcinemaclub.

```
function easyread(noun){
    var out = noun.split(' ').join('');
    return out;
}
```

Function label(number1,number2,number3) will take three numbers, evaluate each mod 1000, and combine them together to a 9-digit integer. For example, label(1001,1002,1003) returns 100200300.

```
function label(sum1,sum2,year){
    var label = 1000000*(sum1%1000) + 1000*(sum2%1000) + year%1000;
    return label;
```

I now want to write a function called sigma, which will take a string with no spaces, break it up character by character, and then add up their indices. So, I'd run a string through easyread, plug it into sigma, which would then refer to bijection in an iteration over each character in the string, and do some maths to return the sum of each bijection(character). I would take whatever sigma outputs, and have it be an input to label. I'm lost on how to make sigma happen, though. Any help?

**Updates:**

This is what I got so far.

```
function sigma(noun){ 
  var domain = easyread(noun) //removes spaces from input noun 
  for(let n = 0; n<domain.length; n++) { 
    //start with n = 0, and stop when n is incrementally larger than the length of our spaces-removed string. 
    let iterative = domain[n]; //not sure what this is bijection(iterative); 
                               //tells the computer to calculate the bijection of each character 
  } //return sum of all bijection(iterative), somehow? }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be helpful if you showed the code that you have put together.  You may also want to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split the string into an array, [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert the letters to numbers and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum them together.

Comment: As an aside: you may want to consider removing words like "the" from the beginning of song titles before doing the calculation, so that, e.g., "The Power of Love" and "Power of Love" would get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are pretty new to `Javascript`, I will try my best to avoid using complex APIs.

Essentially to strip out all the spaces, you will have to do a `string.replace(...)`. Where the API takes in a regular expression pattern. So you will want to do something like `/\s/g` to say I want to "find all spaces within the string" and the 2nd parameter would just be `''`, that is to replace with it with ''.

After that you will want to loop through each characters in the spaceless string value, just do a simple `for-loop` and on each loop call your `bijection()` function.

Consider the code below.

**Example:**

```js
"use strict";
    function bijection(char) {
      // Assuming this is your bijection fn
      console.log("converting character: " + char + " into value..." );
      return 10; // assuming every character is value of 10.
    }

    let test = "one which may  have  spaces ";
    let nospace = test.replace(/\s/g, "");
    let totalValue = 0;

    for(let n = 0; n < nospace.length; n++) {
      let char = nospace[n];
      totalValue += bijection(char);
    }

    console.log("Total Value is => " + totalValue);
```

Comment: Hope this helps. Let me know if you would like to discuss this further

Comment: He has already written the `.replace()` function. It's called `easyread()`. So the code should be `let nospace = easyread(test)`

Comment: I don't quite understand the condition in that for loop, but the rest is managable. How do we now get the sum bijection("t")+bijection("w")+...+bijection("u")+bijection("b") from this loop, though?

Comment: I'm fiddling with it like this

`function sigma(noun){

    var domain = easyread(noun) //removes spaces from input noun

    for(let n = 0; n<domain.length; n++) { //start with n = 0, and stop when n is incrementally larger than the length of our spaces-removed string.

        let iterative = domain[n]; //not sure what this is

        bijection(iterative); //tells the computer to calculate the bijection of each character

    }

//return sum of all bijection(iterative), somehow?

}`

Comment: The loop can be read as "For each character in `nospace` ( or in your code `domain` ). Call your `bijection()` to get the value for that character. Then using the result returned by `bijection` add it to the variable `totalValue`.